# AppCompatDrawableManager.get() vs VectorDrawableCompat.create()

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-vectordrawable

I am using support lib version 24.2.1, and have enabled support vectors with `AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);`

**What is the difference in these functions regarding support vectors?** I was using `VectorDrawableCompat.create(getResources(), R.drawable.my_vector, null)`. But this does not produce a drawable on my test device (Android 4.3) when setting a drawable on a button programmatically like so:

`button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(icon, null, null, null);`

Using `AppCompatDrawableManager.get().getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.my_vector);` (wrapped in a state list selector) seems to work okay, although I can't seem to find the documentation for it.

Comment: `AppCompatDrawableManager` is hidden, use `AppCompatResources#getDrawable` instead

Comment: @pskink `AppCompatResources.getDrawable(...)` instroduced in 24.x.x is a public API shortcut to `AppCompatDrawableManager.get().getDrawable(...)` available sooner.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> What is the difference in these functions regarding support vectors?

`AppCompatResources.getDrawable(...)` will inflate all kinds of drawables including

- vector drawables below API 21 (only if support vector drawables are enabled by build script; read further)
- properly themed AppCompat drawables
- any other drawable obtainable by `ContextCompat.getDrawable(Context, int)`

This method internally calls `AppCompatDrawableManager.get().getDrawable(Context, int)`, which is not part of public API. Both methods equal in function from consumer point of view.

`VectorDrawableCompat.create(...)` will only inflate vector drawables (only if support vector drawables are enabled by build script; read further).

> But this does not produce a drawable on my test device (Android 4.3)

`VectorDrawableCompat.create(...)` will return `null` on error. This can happen if the referenced drawable is not a vector drawable which in turn can happen if you didn't configure the build plugin correctly and PNGs are generated for platforms below API 21.

Activate vector drawables support below API 21 by altering *app module* `build.gradle`:

```
// Gradle Plugin 2.0+  
android {  
  defaultConfig {  
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
  }  
}
```

See [Android Support Library 23.2](http://android-developers.blogspot.cz/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html) blog post for further info.

> I am using support lib version 24.2.1, and have enabled support vectors with `AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true)`

This method does not "enable support vectors". First of all you need to enable support vector drawables in `build.gradle` as said above.

After that this method basically enables support vector drawables inside drawable containers like `LayerDrawable` or `StateListDrawable`.

See [AppCompat — Age of the vectors](https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88#.r0effg5l9) for more info how this can be abused.

Comment: Great okay that makes a little more sense. I had the gradle flag set, but actually I think my error was wrapping the vectors in a state list drawable for use with `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds()`. It seems to be working now for me on 4.3 using straight up vectors and `VectorCompat.create`

Comment: Yes, use the wrapper for compound drawables in XML attributes and the unwrapped vector in `VectorDrawableCompat.create`.

Comment: Wow it's lucky you said that thanks, worth adding to the answer. I had it running but without the wrapper, until I reinstalled and it didn't work. The app seems to hang on to vectors somehow if it manages to create them at least once, so it seems best to reinstall / clear data if experimenting